# Android resolve host name to ip address translation

Tags: java, android

How can I resolve a host name to an IP address on an Android phone?  I do not have access to the /system/etc/hosts file.

Answer (score 1):

[`InetAddress`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html) can do that for you:

```
String ip = InetAddress.getByName("stackoverflow.com").getHostAddress();
// result e.g: "151.101.129.69"
```

This also needs to be done in a background-thread.